# didFailWithError() called many times when location access is change form 'Never' to 'Always'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am developing an app with location services. I want to trigger a local notification when the user is turn off the location. But when the user turn the location from 'Never' to 'Always', the location delegate method

```
-(void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
```

is invoked 3 times, because of that notification triggered more than one time. Can we stop to invoke that delegate method more than one time?

Comment: Just count the notifications and do nothing after first one.

Comment: You can't since that delegate is called by `CLLocationManager`, instead you can check the error type for appropriate action.